# jquery mobile can't post result in arabic

Tags: jquery, sql, mobile, character-encoding

I made a form with action and method=post, **this code to find a result from database**. so when i try it with english words, it's work correctly but when i use other language like arabic it doesnt work.so the probem on the charset. i used:

```
charset=windows-1256
```

this is good for arabic but i dont now why the code does not word!

the html form :

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">
<input type="search" name="find" />
<input type="submit" value="search" />
<form/>
```

i change the submit to this code but all the same!

```
<button type="submit" data-theme="b" name="submit" value="submit-value">search</button>
```

php code :

```
$find=trim($_POST['find']);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM s_output WHERE name LIKE '%$find%' ORDER BY BINARY name");
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to use UTF-8 encoding everywhere. On your page, and in your database.

Comment: i did use it, and the database encoding is UTF-8 too, but it doesn't work. i think there is somthing in the jquery code need to be change

Comment: charset=windows-1256 = windows encoding. Is this what you have set on your page?

Comment: yes this is the charset i used it on all the pages, cos it's work correctly with all browser in web version but it doesnt work with mobile version

Comment: OK, that's your problem. You need to use UTF-8.